# Htaccess rule on sitemap filename for multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, security, seo, sitemap

I have 2 domains: `firstdomain.com` and `seconddomain.com` that share the same platform.

My sitemap files are named:

```
www.firstdomain.com/sitemap/www.firstdomain.com.xml
www.seconddomain.com/sitemap/www.seconddomain.com.xml
```

Google can access `www.firstdomain.com/sitemap/www.seconddomain.com.xml`

Is it possible to prevent this with an `.htaccess` rule? Can I check the domain name specified in the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Can this work ?

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !(%{HTTP_HOST}\.xml)$ [L,R=404]
```